# How to include external DLL inside the .EXE package using netbeans native packaging?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, netbeans-platform, vlcj

I am doing **javaFX desktop application** (windows & Mac support) which has **vlc player library dependency**. To remove the dependancy I have to include all the libary files into my application and during the installation I need install the library files into **C:\Program Files\MyApp** folder.

I have been using netbeans 8.0.2 which provides **.EXE** package by netbeans native packaging. Now my problem is **I am not able to place my vlc library files inside the exe package**. Please give your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an installer package with your application exe and the 3rd party libraries using [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) or Wix. Plus for Mac you should look at [appbundler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) for converting jar to app files.

Answer (score 0):

first you wrap your .jar file to .exe using launncher4j then you will be able to see an exe file next you need to create and setup wizard for that you can use installsheild or innosetup, in these setup wizard you can specify the files you need to place in the program files folder. while installing the software the files will be copied by the setup wizard itself